# Problem import customers from CSV Prestashop 1.7.4.0

Tags: csv, import, prestashop

We can not import customers in our prestashop. It is a clean and new prestashop, we take the native CSV file from prestashop and it gives the same errors when inserting the clients.
Does this also happen to someone else?

```
La dirección de correo electrónico jesusortigosa@hotmail.com (ID: 1068) no se puede validar.
La propiedad Customer->telephone está vacía.
La dirección de correo electrónico norbertoal1@hotmail.com (ID: 1067) no se puede validar.
La propiedad Customer->telephone está vacía.
La dirección de correo electrónico adam.jardiners@gmail.com (ID: 1066) no se puede validar.
La propiedad Customer->telephone está vacía.
La dirección de correo electrónico ptorresmartos@gmail.com (ID: 1065) no se puede validar.
La propiedad Customer->telephone está vacía.
La dirección de correo electrónico bruno.mes.rub@gmail.com (ID: 1064) no se puede validar.
La propiedad Customer->telephone está vacía.
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

try with add phone number in your file (ex: 0102030405)

Regards